# Convertible or not?

Tags: java

Let say that class `A` and `B` inherit class `C`.

```
public class A extends C {}

public class B extends C {}
```

How can we convert type, i.e

```
A a;
B b;
a = (A) b;
```

I tried but it announce that `error: inconvertible type`.

Comment: Can add an example of a `B` which is also an `A`? Note: you are converting the reference, the object referenced doesn't change when you cast.

Comment: You can not. A is not a subclass of B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only cast a reference if there is an "is a" relationship. There is no "is a" relationship between `A` and `B`. `A` *is a* `C`, and `B` *is a* `C`, but `B` *is not an* `A`.

Consider: Both apples (`B`) and oranges (`A`) are fruit (`C`), but apples are not oranges.

---

Note: In Java, "conversion" means "turning something into something else." You can *convert* a `String` to an `int`, for instance, via `Integer.parseInt`. That's not what the casting operator does; the casting operator just changes the type of *reference* you have to a thing, not the actual thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast `B` to `A` because B doesn't extend A. Just because both extends `C`, it doesn't mean they're the convertible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "convert" it for few good reasons, but foremost:

If A has a field or method B does not have, it would not make sense to call them. The proper way is to code against your superclass C, which allows A or B as its implementation.