# I have some issue about casting in java

Tags: java, casting

```
public class A {
    private String superStr;

    public String getSuperStr() {
        return superStr;
    }

    public void setSuperStr(String superStr) {
        this.superStr = superStr;
    }   
}
```

```
public class B extends A {
    private String subStr;

    public String getSubStr() {
        return subStr;
    }

    public void setSubStr(String subStr) {
        this.subStr = subStr;
    }   
}
```

And I expect result likes below

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        A a = fuc();

        B b = new B();

        b = (B) a;

        b.setSubStr("subStr");

        System.out.println(a.getSuperStr() +  b.getSubStr());       
    }

    private static A fuc() {
        A  a = new A();
        a.setSuperStr("super");

        return a;
    }
```

but java.lang.ClassCastException is ocuured.

How can I cast this?
I want use subclass variable and super class variable.

thank you

Comment: an A is not a B, so you cannot cast an instance of B to A. Suppose, A  = Human, B = Mutant (is a Human with superpowers), you cannot take an ordinary Human and tell it to use its superpowers since it is not a Mutant to begin with.

Comment: You can cast a B to an A, but not the other way around.  Inheritance means IS-A: a child IS-A parent.  The Liskov substitution principle is satisfied because you can use a child everywhere that a parent is called for.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38325842/convertible-or-not/38325882#38325882

Answer (score 2):

> How can I cast this?

You can't. You can only cast when the object in question has an "is a" relationship with the type. In your case, you have an `A` object (the one from `fn`), which is not a `B`. (All `B` objects are `A`s, because `B` extends `A`, but not all `A` objects are `B`s.)

Consider: Let's call `B` `Bird` and `A` `Animal`: A `Bird` is an `Animal`, but not all `Animal`s are `Bird`s. So we can treat all `Bird`s as `Animal`s, but we cannot treat all `Animal`s as `Bird`s. When you're using a variable of a given type to refer to an object, you're treating the object as being of that type (e.g., `B b = (B)a` tries to treat the `Animal` `a` as a `Bird`).

---

Side note: There's no point to the indicated part of the code:

```
B b = new B();
// ^^^^^^^^^^
b = (B) a;
```

Since the very next line assigns to `b` (well, it would if it would compile), there's no purpose served by doing `new B()` and assigning that to `b` just beforehand. (Unless the `B` constructor has side-effects, which is generally a Bad Idea™.)

Answer (score 0):

[Casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) a particular object to another types does not magically convert it into an instance of that class (or at least [not in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)); Therefore, the object referenced by variable `a` does not e.g. have the field `subStr` to use despite that the object referenced by `b` after executing `B b = new B();` does.

Answer (score 0):

The others have already explained why you can't do that. I'm here to give you a simple alternative. Your B class could have a constructor that had an A as argument and you would simply wrap that A so you could "transform" it to a B. Using that your code would look way more clean, it would actually work and you were following a good design pattern. For more information check the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)